# Using ODBC connection with Azure Data Studio

Tags: database-connection, azure-data-studio

In order to connect to an IBM DB2 database, I am using DBeaver with an ODBC type of connection. But since I found Azure Data Studio very lightweight and portable, I want to ask if there is a way to connect to such databases because all I get is *Microsoft SQL Server* as connection type.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Azure Data Studio connects to SQL Server and Azure SQL.  You can install extensions from within Azure Data Studio for Postgres, MySQL, and MongoDB.  There is currently no extension for DB2 or ODBC.

There has been at least one DB2 feature request filed at the [Azure Data Studio Github.](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/)  However, the one I found was closed with "This feature is currently out of scope, and we do not plan to work on it in a currently planned release."